# If $G/H$ is cyclic, where $H$ is a subgroup of $Z(G)$, then $G$ is abelian.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, cyclic-groups, quotient-group

> **Theorem 9.3** *$G/Z$ Theorem.
>
> Let $G$ be a group and let $Z(G)$ be the center of $G$. If $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic, then $G$ is Abelian.
>
> $\mathsf{PROOF}$ Since $G$ is Abelian is equivalent to $Z(G)=G$, it suffices to show that the only element of $G/Z(G)$ is the identity coset $Z(G)$. To this end let $G/Z(G)=\langle gZ(G)\rangle$ and let $a\in G$. Then there exists an integer $i$ such that $aZ(G)=(gZ(G))^i = g^iZ(G)$. Thus, $a=g^iz$ for some $z\in Z(G)$. Since both $g^i$ and $z$ belong to $C(g)$, so does $a$. Becaus $a$ is an arbitrary element of $G$ this means that every element of $G$ commutes with $g$ so $g\in Z(G)$. Thus, $gZ(G)=Z(G)$ is the only element of $G/Z(G)$. $\Box$
>
> A few remarks about Theorem 9.3 are in order. First, our proof shows that a better result is possible. If $G/H$ is cyclic, where $H$ is a subgroup of $Z(G)$, then $G$ is Abelian. Second, in practice, it is the contrapositive of the theorem that is most often used - that is, if $G$ is non-Abelian, then $G/Z(G)$ is not cyclic. For example, it follows immediately from the statement and Lagrange’s Theorem that a non-Abelian group of order $pq$, where $p$ and $q$ are prime, must have trivial center. Third, if $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic, it must be trivial.

In the book Contemporary abstract algebra, page 194, there's a result corresponding to theorem 9.3 which is

> If $G/H$ is cyclic, where $H$ is a subgroup of $Z(G)$, then $G$ is abelian.

My question is - is there any way to prove this result using the same method used to prove the **Theorem 9.3** ?
I've attached an image of the proof of **Theorem 9.3**.

**My proof:** [*In short*]
$$\begin{align*}
 G/H &= \ \langle gH\rangle \\
   &\implies \text{for any} \ a,b \in G,a\in g^iH \ \text{and} \ \ b\in g^jH.
\\ \therefore a&=g^ih_1 \ \text{and} \ b=g^jh_2.
\\ \therefore  ab &= (g^ih_1)(g^jh_2) 
\\ &= g^{i+j}h_1h_2
\\ &= (g^jh_2)(g^ih_1)
\\ &= ba.
\end{align*}$$

Comment: That will do, but since $H\leqslant Z(G)$ we get that $G/H$ cyclic implies $G/Z(G)$ cyclic so result is an immediate corollary of 9.3.

Comment: Thanks ancientmathematician...this is what I was looking for.

Comment: Please do not use images: they are not searchable, and users who use screen readers may be unable to read them. The site has strong mathematical typesetting capabilities: use them.

Comment: The image that I used contains a lot of writing and if I were to write it then the length would be too long and it would take so much time of mine...I could've just given the reference of the book only but thought that the whole theorem might help users. That's why I only used it.

Comment: @Pritam: Nevertheless, images are strongly discouraged as a way to convey text. Quoting would have been better.

Comment: There you go; I hope you used the three minutes you saved by not typing it out well.

Answer (score 2):

The more general result can indeed be proved using the same method. May I present a few additional, general results that would help in organising the proof:

> **Lemma 1.** Let $G$ be an arbitrary group, $H \trianglelefteq G$ a *normal* subgroup and $S, T \subseteq G$ subsets such that $H=\langle S \rangle$ ($S$ is a generating system for $H$) and $G/H=\langle \sigma(T) \rangle$ (the canonical image of $T$ generates the quotient), where $\sigma \colon G \to G/H$ denotes the canonical surjection. Then $G=\langle S \cup T \rangle$, i.e. $G$ is generated by the union $S \cup T$.

> **Lemma 2.** Let $G$ be an arbitrary group and $S \subseteq G$ a generating system consisting of *mutually* commuting elements (in formal expression, $G=\langle S \rangle$ and $S \subseteq \mathrm{C}_G(S)$). Then $G$ is abelian.

These two lemata suffice to prove the following:

> **Proposition.** Let $G$ be an arbitrary group and $H \leqslant \mathrm{Z}(G)$ a *central* subgroup such that $G/H$ is cyclic. Then $G$ is abelian.

*Proof.* As the quotient $G/H$ is cyclic, there exists $a \in G$ such that $\sigma(a)$ generates $G/H$ (where $\sigma$ denotes the canonical surjection, as above). It then follows by virtue of lemma 1 that $G$ is generated by $H \cup \{a\}$ ($H$ generates itself, of course) and since $H$ is central -- consisting of elements which commute with anything in $G$ -- $H \cup \{a\}$ is easily seen to consist of pairwise commuting elements and hence lemma 2 applies. $\Box$

Let me know if you would like to see proofs for the two lemata (they are very simple).